# How to change a property of parent-viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

again I need your help.

I'm building a WPF app, where I have a MainViewModel for a page, that contents a treeview. This treeview is bound to a ProjectTreeViewModel, that is created by the MainViewModel.

Now my ProjectTreeViewModel catches a click-event (using a relay command), that tells it, which node was clicked.

I need this information inside my MainViewmodel. How do I transfer it there?

**EDIT... a runnable example**

some Data to show in the tree:

```
using WpfApp1.Models;

namespace WpfApp1.Dataprovider
{
  class PlcAddressData
  {
    public static PlcAddress GetPlcRootItems(string projectName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectName))
            projectName = "Projekt-Datenpunkte";

        return new PlcAddress
        {
            Name = projectName,
            NodeId = 0,
            Children =
            {
                new PlcAddress
                {
                    Name = "Allgemein",
                    Comment = "allgemeine Datenpunkte",
                    NodeId = 1,
                    ParentNodeId = 0
                },
                new PlcAddress
                {
                    Name = "Infrastruktur",
                    Comment = "interne Datenpunkte der Infrastruktur",
                    ParentNodeId = 0,
                    NodeId = 2
                },
                new PlcAddress
                {
                    Name = "lokale IOs",
                    Comment = "Datenpunkte der SPS-Baugruppe",
                    ParentNodeId = 0,
                    NodeId = 3,
                    Children =
                    {
                        new PlcAddress
                        {
                            Name = "IO 0",
                            Comment = "first Channel of Plc-IO-Card",
                            NodeId = 4,
                            ParentNodeId = 3
                        },
                        new PlcAddress
                        {
                            Name = "IO 1",
                            Comment = "second Channel of Plc-IO-Card",
                            NodeId = 5,
                            ParentNodeId = 3
                        },
                        new PlcAddress
                        {
                            Name = "IO 2",
                            Comment = "third Channel of Plc-IO-Card",
                            NodeId = 6,
                            ParentNodeId = 3
                        },
                        new PlcAddress
                        {
                            Name = "IO 3",
                            Comment = "forth Channel of Plc-IO-Card",
                            NodeId = 7,
                            ParentNodeId = 3
                        },
                        new PlcAddress
                        {
                            Name = "IO 4",
                            Comment = "fifth Channel of Plc-IO-Card",
                            NodeId = 8,
                            ParentNodeId = 3
                        },
                        new PlcAddress
                        {
                            Name = "IO 5",
                            Comment = "sixth Channel of Plc-IO-Card",
                            NodeId = 9,
                            ParentNodeId = 3
                        },
                        new PlcAddress
                        {
                            Name = "IO 6",
                            Comment = "seventh Channel of Plc-IO-Card",
                            NodeId = 10,
                            ParentNodeId = 3
                        },
                        new PlcAddress
                        {
                            Name = "IO 7",
                            Comment = "eighth Channel of Plc-IO-Card",
                            NodeId = 11,
                            ParentNodeId = 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
  }
}
```

The **PlcAddress**-model (data for treeview-item):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApp1.Models
{
  public class PlcAddress
  {
    private List<PlcAddress> _children = new List<PlcAddress>();
    public List<PlcAddress> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set { _children = value; }
    }

    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public int ParentNodeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
  }
}
```

A **RelayCommand**:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels.Commands
{
  public class RelayCommand : ICommand
  {
    #region Fields
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null){ }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

The **MainViewModel**:

```
using WpfApp1.Models;

namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels
{
  public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        LoadProjectTree();

    }
    private void LoadProjectTree()
    {
        PlcAddress RootItem = Dataprovider.PlcAddressData.GetPlcRootItems("Parent Node of Project");
        _projectTree = new ProjectTreeviewModel(RootItem);
        _projectTree.PropertyChanged += ProjectTreePropertyChanged;
    }
    private void ProjectTreePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectTreeviewModel selectedNode = (ProjectTreeviewModel)sender;
        System.Console.WriteLine("selectedNode changed:" + selectedNode.SelectedNode);
        SelectedNode = selectedNode.SelectedNode;
        //MessageBox.Show("Some Property changed");
    }

    #region Properties
    private string _selectedNode;
    public string SelectedNode {
        get { return _selectedNode; } 
        set
        {
            _selectedNode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedNode");
        }
    }
    private ProjectTreeviewModel _projectTree;
    public ProjectTreeviewModel ProjectTree
    {
        get { return _projectTree; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

The **PlcAddressViewModel** to show as item in the tree

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using WpfApp1.Models;

namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels
{
  public class PlcAddressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    #region Data
    private Collection<PlcAddressViewModel> _children;
    readonly PlcAddressViewModel _parent;
    readonly PlcAddress _plcAddress;

    bool _isExpanded;
    bool _isSelected;
    #endregion Data

    #region Constructors
    public PlcAddressViewModel(PlcAddress plcAddress) : this(plcAddress, null)
    {
    }

    private PlcAddressViewModel(PlcAddress plcAddress, PlcAddressViewModel parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
        _plcAddress = plcAddress;

        _children = new Collection<PlcAddressViewModel>(
            (from child in _plcAddress.Children
             select new PlcAddressViewModel(child, this))
             .ToList<PlcAddressViewModel>());
    }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region AddressProperties
    public Collection<PlcAddressViewModel> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set { _children = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _plcAddress.Name; }
    }
    public string Comment
    {
        get { return _plcAddress.Comment; }
    }
    #endregion AddressProperties

    #region Presentation Members

    #region IsExpanded
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isExpanded)
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }

            // Expand all the way up to the root
            if (_isExpanded && _parent != null)
                _parent.IsExpanded = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion IsExpanded

    #region IsSelected
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            if (_isSelected)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Nodeselected: " + this._plcAddress.Name);
            }
            return this._isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isSelected)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion IsSelected

    #region Parent
    public PlcAddressViewModel Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
    }
    #endregion Parent

    #endregion Presentation Members

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged Members
  }
}
```

The **ProjectTreeViewModel** where the selectionchanged is recognized

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using WpfApp1.Models;
using WpfApp1.ViewModels.Commands;

namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels
{
  public class ProjectTreeviewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    #region Data
    public RelayCommand TreeNodeSelected { get; private set; }
    readonly ReadOnlyCollection<PlcAddressViewModel> _rootNodes;
    readonly PlcAddressViewModel _rootAddress;
    #endregion Data

    #region Constructor
    public ProjectTreeviewModel(PlcAddress rootAddress)
    {
        _rootAddress = new PlcAddressViewModel(rootAddress);

        _rootNodes = new ReadOnlyCollection<PlcAddressViewModel>(
            new PlcAddressViewModel[]
            {
                _rootAddress
            });

        TreeNodeSelected = new RelayCommand(ExecuteTreeNodeSelected, canExecuteMethod);
    }
    #endregion Constructor

    #region Properties
    private string _selectedNode;
    public string SelectedNode
    {
        get { return _selectedNode; }
        set
        {
            _selectedNode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedNode");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region RootNode
    public ReadOnlyCollection<PlcAddressViewModel> ProjectNode
    {
        get { return _rootNodes; }
    }
    #endregion RootNode

    #region Commands
    private bool canExecuteMethod(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    private void ExecuteTreeNodeSelected(object parameter)
    {
        PlcAddressViewModel selectedNode = (PlcAddressViewModel)parameter;
        Console.WriteLine("Found this node: " + selectedNode.Name);
        SelectedNode = selectedNode.Name;
    }
    #endregion Commands
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

last but not least, the **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    >


<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TreeView DataContext="{Binding ProjectTree}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectNode}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
              x:Name="ProjectTree" Margin="0 0 2 0" Grid.Column="0">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TreeNodeSelected}" 
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ProjectTree, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- following Texblock is bound to a MainViewModels property -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedNode}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

... and its **codebehind**:

```
using System.Windows;
using WpfApp1.ViewModels;

namespace WpfApp1
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
  }
}
```

...after some hours of experiments, I solved it. The solution is in the snippets above and I don't know if that is the best way. I did it the folling way:

The Command-method `ExecuteTreeNodeSelected` changes the public property `SelectedNode`. That fires a notification `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedNode");`.

When creating the Treeviewmodel, in MainViewModel, I added an eventlistener to the PropertyChanged-event of the TreeViewModel `_projectTree.PropertyChanged += ProjectTreePropertyChanged;`. This Event changes the `SelectedNode`-property of the MainViewModel, that notifies the UI.

Thanks for your patience

Comment: You can write some kind of event to pass it of use event aggregator for that

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, what you are trying to tell me. Could you please provide a link or example?

Answer (score 0):

This is the ViewModel base class that I use for hierarchical data to be displayed in a TreeView control.

```
/// <summary>
/// A base class for items that can be displayed in a TreeView or other hierarchical display
/// </summary>
public class perTreeViewItemViewModelBase : perViewModelBase
{
    // a dummy item used in lazy loading mode, ensuring that each node has at least one child so that the expand button is shown
    private static perTreeViewItemViewModelBase LazyLoadingChildIndicator { get; } 
        = new perTreeViewItemViewModelBase { Caption = "Loading Data ..." };

    private bool InLazyLoadingMode { get; set; }
    private bool LazyLoadTriggered { get; set; }
    private bool LazyLoadCompleted { get; set; }
    private bool RequiresLazyLoad => InLazyLoadingMode && !LazyLoadTriggered;

    // Has Children been overridden (e.g. to point at some private internal collection) 
    private bool LazyLoadChildrenOverridden => InLazyLoadingMode && !Equals(LazyLoadChildren, _childrenList);

    private readonly perObservableCollection<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> _childrenList 
        = new perObservableCollection<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase>();

    /// <summary>
    /// LazyLoadingChildIndicator ensures a visible expansion toggle button in lazy loading mode 
    /// </summary>
    protected void SetLazyLoadingMode()
    {
        ClearChildren();
        _childrenList.Add(LazyLoadingChildIndicator);

        IsExpanded = false;
        InLazyLoadingMode = true;
        LazyLoadTriggered = false;
        LazyLoadCompleted = false;
    }

    private string _caption;

    public string Caption
    {
        get => _caption;
        set => Set(nameof(Caption), ref _caption, value);
    }

    public void ClearChildren()
    {
        _childrenList.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new child item to this TreeView item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="child"></param>
    public void AddChild(perTreeViewItemViewModelBase child)
    {
        if (LazyLoadChildrenOverridden)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't call AddChild for an item with LazyLoad mode set & LazyLoadChildren has been overridden");

        if (_childrenList.Any() && _childrenList.First() == LazyLoadingChildIndicator)
            _childrenList.Clear();

        _childrenList.Add(child);

        SetChildPropertiesFromParent(child);
    }

    protected void SetChildPropertiesFromParent(perTreeViewItemViewModelBase child)
    { 
        child.Parent = this;

        // if this node is checked then all new children added are set checked 
        if (IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
            child.SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(true);

        ReCalculateNodeCheckState();
    }

    protected void ReCalculateNodeCheckState()
    {
        var item = this;

        while (item != null)
        {
            if (item.Children.Any() && !Equals(item.Children.FirstOrDefault(), LazyLoadingChildIndicator))
            {
                var hasIndeterminateChild = item.Children.Any(c => c.IsEnabled && !c.IsChecked.HasValue);

                if (hasIndeterminateChild)
                    item.SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(null);
                else
                {
                    var hasSelectedChild = item.Children.Any(c => c.IsEnabled && c.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault());
                    var hasUnselectedChild = item.Children.Any(c => c.IsEnabled && !c.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault());

                    if (hasUnselectedChild && hasSelectedChild)
                        item.SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(null);
                    else
                        item.SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(hasSelectedChild);
                }
            }

            item = item.Parent;
        }
    }

    private void SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(bool? value)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));

            foreach (var child in Children)
                if (child.IsEnabled)
                    child.SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(value);
        }
    }

    private void SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(bool? value)
    {
        _isChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add multiple children to this TreeView item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="children"></param>
    public void AddChildren(IEnumerable<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> children)
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
            AddChild(child);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove a child item from this TreeView item
    /// </summary>
    public void RemoveChild(perTreeViewItemViewModelBase child)
    {
        _childrenList.Remove(child);
        child.Parent = null;

        ReCalculateNodeCheckState();
    }

    public perTreeViewItemViewModelBase Parent { get; private set; }

    private bool? _isChecked = false;

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set
        {
            if (Set(nameof(IsChecked), ref _isChecked, value))
            {
                foreach (var child in Children)
                    if (child.IsEnabled)
                        child.SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(value);

                Parent?.ReCalculateNodeCheckState();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isExpanded;

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get => _isExpanded;
        set
        {
            if (Set(nameof(IsExpanded), ref _isExpanded, value) && value && RequiresLazyLoad)
                TriggerLazyLoading();
        }
    }

    private bool _isEnabled = true;

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => _isEnabled;
        set => Set(nameof(IsEnabled), ref _isEnabled, value);
    }

    public void TriggerLazyLoading()
    {
        var unused = DoLazyLoadAsync();
    }

    private async Task DoLazyLoadAsync()
    {
        if (LazyLoadTriggered)
            return;

        LazyLoadTriggered = true;

        var lazyChildrenResult = await LazyLoadFetchChildren()
            .EvaluateFunctionAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        LazyLoadCompleted = true;

        if (lazyChildrenResult.IsCompletedOk)
        {
            var lazyChildren = lazyChildrenResult.Data;

            foreach (var child in lazyChildren)
                SetChildPropertiesFromParent(child);

            // If LazyLoadChildren has been overridden then just refresh the check state (using the new children) 
            // and update the check state (in case any of the new children is already set as checked)
            if (LazyLoadChildrenOverridden)
                ReCalculateNodeCheckState();
            else
                AddChildren(lazyChildren); // otherwise add the new children to the base collection.
        }

        RefreshChildren();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the children for this node, in Lazy-Loading Mode
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual Task<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase[]> LazyLoadFetchChildren()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new perTreeViewItemViewModelBase[0]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the Children property
    /// </summary>
    public void RefreshChildren()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Children));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// In LazyLoading Mode, the Children property can be set to something other than
    /// the base _childrenList collection - e.g as the union ot two internal collections
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> Children => LazyLoadCompleted
                                                                ? LazyLoadChildren
                                                                : _childrenList;

    /// <summary>
    /// How are the children held when in lazy loading mode.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Override this as required in descendent classes - e.g. if Children is formed from a union
    /// of multiple internal child item collections (of different types) which are populated in LazyLoadFetchChildren()
    /// </remarks>
    protected virtual IEnumerable<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> LazyLoadChildren => _childrenList;

    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            // if unselecting we don't care about anything else other than simply updating the property
            if (!value)
            {
                Set(nameof(IsSelected), ref _isSelected, false);
                return;
            }

            // Build a priority queue of operations
            //
            // All operations relating to tree item expansion are added with priority = DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, so that they are
            // sorted before any operations relating to selection (which have priority = DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle).
            // This ensures that the visual container for all items are created before any selection operation is carried out.
            //
            // First expand all ancestors of the selected item - those closest to the root first
            //
            // Expanding a node will scroll as many of its children as possible into view - see perTreeViewItemHelper, but these scrolling
            // operations will be added to the queue after all of the parent expansions.
            var ancestorsToExpand = new Stack<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase>();

            var parent = Parent;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                if (!parent.IsExpanded)
                    ancestorsToExpand.Push(parent);

                parent = parent.Parent;
            }

            while (ancestorsToExpand.Any())
            {
                var parentToExpand = ancestorsToExpand.Pop();
                perDispatcherHelper.AddToQueue(() => parentToExpand.IsExpanded = true, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
            }

            // Set the item's selected state - use DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle so this operation is executed after all
            // expansion operations, no matter when they were added to the queue.
            //
            // Selecting a node will also scroll it into view - see perTreeViewItemHelper
            perDispatcherHelper.AddToQueue(() => Set(nameof(IsSelected), ref _isSelected, true), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);

            // note that by rule, a TreeView can only have one selected item, but this is handled automatically by 
            // the control - we aren't required to manually unselect the previously selected item.

            // execute all of the queued operations in descending DispatcherPriority order (expansion before selection)
            var unused = perDispatcherHelper.ProcessQueueAsync();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Caption;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// What's the total number of child nodes beneath this one
    /// </summary>
    public int ChildCount => Children.Count() + Children.Sum(c => c.ChildCount);
}
```

Amongst other features, it includes a Parent property, so each item in the data structure knows its immediate ancestor.

Rather than using an event to handle an item being clicked, I've created a behaviour to add a bindable selected item property to a TreeView. This allows a change of selection to be detected for means other than a direct mouse click, such as the user pressing the arrow keys.

```
public class perTreeViewHelper : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public object BoundSelectedItem
    {
        get => GetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSelectedItem",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(perTreeViewHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnBoundSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnBoundSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue is perTreeViewItemViewModelBase item)
            item.IsSelected = true;
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object obj, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> args)
    {
        BoundSelectedItem = args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

More details on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't read your blog yet but I have to clarify that I didn't mean parent as the parent node of the clicked treenode. I mean the The MainViewmodel, that holds the Viewmodels for the Treeview and other controls. My problem ist, that I don't know how my MainViewmodel gets informed about which node was clicked. ...now I'll go and read your blog :)

Comment: If you implement the bound selected item property as outlined in my answer, that can be bound to a property on the main view model.

Comment: Sorry if I have to ask like a total noob... that is exactly my knowledge gap. In my Treeviewmodel I have a command that is triggered. from this point, I have a parameter, that holds the selected node. How do I transfer (bind) this, outside this viewmodel?

Comment: I don't get the purpose of your ParentViewModel class. Take a look at the demo project for my blog post https://github.com/Peregrine66/PeregrinesView/tree/master/blog/08a%20-%20WPF%20Behaviors%20-%20TreeView - the MainViewModel contains a collection of perTreeViewItemViewModelBase descendents (RootItemVms) that are bound to the ItemsSource property of the TreeView control as well as the SelectedItem property that is bound via the behaviour class to the selected item in the TreeView.

Comment: Sorry, that is very much tooo much for me. I created a runnable project and will edit my question above.